# Javascript on wordpress posts

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to use javascript on my wordpress post for over 2 hours now.
I researched everything there is to research, and it still isn't working.

I've made sure to paste my code in the "text" tab of wordpress.

Can I get some help?

Here's my code:

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!-- 
              // Array of day names
              var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                  "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

              // Array of month Names
              var monthNames = new Array(
              "January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
              "August","September","October","November","December");

              var now = new Date();
              document.write(dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
              monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
              now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());

              // -->
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just do this in PHP?

Comment: Because this is a premade script, so I find it more convenient to just use it. I am not capable of recoding this in PHP.

Comment: get rid of `<!-- ` in the begining

Comment: @deepak, I just tried and still, nothing shows up on my post when I view it.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege Where are you going to display the date? Is it the date of the post itself?

Comment: @Jon Koops, it's in the post itself. I'm posting it as part of the content.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege If that is the case, I'd strongly recommend using PHP to display the date. Both for users without JavaScript and search engines who index the page. What is the theme you are using?

Comment: @Jon Koops, I'm using GAMELEON theme.

Comment: On a sidenote, both `language="Javascript"` and `<!-- // -->` are no longer required.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege Ah I see, it's a purchased theme. Look for the `single.php`file in `wp-content/themes/gameleon`, and have a look at the Wordpress formatting date and time guide (http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time).

Comment: @Jon Koops, there was nothing in single.php related to time/date.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege I seem to have misunderstand you, you're posting it as part of the post?

Comment: @MichaelDelvege What are your intentions with this script? What is it's purpose?

Comment: @Jon Koops, my intentions were to display the date inside the post.
It has been resolved, I just did what Console has said, and removed all the white spaces.

Thanks Jon Koops for your time and help.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege Just the date as it is right now? Something like: It is now `Thursday 3rd of October`?

Comment: @Jon Koops, Yes. This is what I was intending to do with the script.

Comment: @MichaelDelvege There are plenty of Wordpress plugins that provide that in a shortcode. For example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-shortcodes/

Comment: @MichaelDelvege This would also be a lot less effort ;)

Comment: @Jon Koops, arggg, if only I had thought of that :P.
Thanks for the idea man, this'll save me a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the white spaces and line breaks in your script. The WordPress is appending `p tags` to your code because of white spaces and line breaks and your code looks like this on execution:

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!-- 
              // Array of day names
              var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
                  "Thursday","Friday","Saturday");</p>
<p>              // Array of month Names
              var monthNames = new Array(
              "January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
              "August","September","October","November","December");</p>
<p>              var now = new Date();
              document.write(dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
              monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
              now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());</p>
<p>              // -->
</script>
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  // Array of day names
  var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
  // Array of month Names
  var monthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
  var now = new Date();
  document.write(dayNames[now.getDay()] + ", " + 
  monthNames[now.getMonth()] + " " + 
  now.getDate() + ", " + now.getFullYear());
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Note that since HTML5 the `type` attrubute is no longer required and defaults to `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of Wordpress plugins that provide that in a shortcode. For example: http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-shortcodes, this also a lot less cumbersome than including a script every time you post.

Answer (score 0):

what wp verion are you running. in wp 3.6.1, if you add js code in post editor, wp will add `<p>` tags around things in script. if you remove the comments `<!-- blah -->`, wp adds cdata around the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
...code...
//]]>
</script>
```

but in frontend output it changes the last part of cdata `//]]>` to `// ]]&gt;`

i cant offer a solution as this would require an external js file. that being said, move js code to external file and all will be rosy

Comment: This did not work for me, but thanks for helping out man. I have it resolved.